# Crawler4j ImageCrawler String args

Tags: java, web-crawler, crawler4j

I´m trying to start the crawler4j example of:
[crawler4j](https://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/source/browse/src/test/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/imagecrawler/?r=8d76f7dec94d409d6a7f65a05392a65bc2222031)

When I start the ImageCrawlController I allready fail by the first step args.length < 3, because its 0. How can I make sure, that args is bigger then 3?

```
public class ImageCrawlController {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length < 3) {
      System.out.println("Needed parameters: ");
      System.out.println("\t rootFolder (it will contain intermediate crawl data)");
      System.out.println("\t numberOfCralwers (number of concurrent threads)");
      System.out.println("\t storageFolder (a folder for storing downloaded images)");
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How dou you invoke your program? From the command line, from within an IDE? You need to pass it the three arguments that your program expects, e.g. `java ImageCrawlController your/root/folder 4 your/storage/folder`.

Comment: thank you I found it storaged in that folder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> '... how can I put a value in the main-function for args? The
>   main-function always starts with args = 0.'

In eclipse: RUN-> RUN CONFIGURATION. In left menu select Java application. Now select tab: ARGUMENTS.

You can call them: `System.out.println(args[1]);  ///<-2`

[image: add arguments, separate them whitespace]